# Does WithContext method need to panic if context is nil?

Tags: go, gorilla, go-redis

I want to write a `WithContext` method for a struct and am taking inspiration from `net/http`'s [`Request.WithContext`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/request.go#L355).

My question is: why does `Request.WithContext` panic if the context is nil:

```golang
func (r *Request) WithContext(ctx context.Context) *Request {
    if ctx == nil {
        panic("nil context")
    }
    ...
}
```

And should mine as well?

For more context on why I want to create a `WithContext` method: I am implementing an interface that does not provide a context parameter in its signature but believe the implementation requires it.

More specifically, I am writing a Redis backend for [`gorilla/session`](https://github.com/gorilla/sessions) using the [official Redis client for Go](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8), where the [`Get`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8#Client.Get) and [`Set`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-redis/redis/v8#Client.Set) methods take `context.Context`.

The idea is that my redis store will be shallow copied with the new context object, when needed, and then used:

```golang
type redisStore struct {
    codecs  []securecookie.Codec
    backend Backend // custom interface for Redis client
    options *sessions.Options
    ctx     context.Context
}

func (s *redisStore) WithContext(ctx context.Context) *redisStore {
    if ctx == nil {
        panic("nil context")
    }
    s2 := new(redisStore)
    *s2 = *s
    s2.ctx = ctx
    return s2
}

// Backend

type Backend interface {
    Set(context.Context, string, interface{}) error
    Get(context.Context, string) (string, error)
    Del(context.Context, string) error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of panicking is to "fail fast" and reject a `nil` context without changing the function signature.

If the function does not panic then it must return error in order to reject a bad input:

```
func (r *Request) WithContext(ctx context.Context) (*Request, error) {
    if ctx == nil {
        return nil, errors.New("nil ctx")
    }
    ...
}
```

And then who calls this function must handle the error to avoid using an invalid request:

```
request, err = request.WithContext(nil)
if err != nil {
   
}
```

By handling the error you are introducing a control flow branch, and you lose method chaining. You also cannot immediately use `WithContext` return value into a function parameter:

```
// cannot do, because WithContext returns an error too
data, err := fetchDataWithContext(request.WithContext(ctx), otherParam)
```

Also it would create an error instance that will be eventually garbage collected. This all is cumbersome, poor usability and unnecessary alloc simply for saying "don't give me a nil context".

About creating a redis store with a context, the context documentation is clear:

> Package context defines the Context type, which carries deadlines, cancellation signals, and other request-scoped values across API boundaries and between processes.

The important detail is **request-scoped**. So setting a context in the redis client itself is contrary to this recommendation. You should pass context values at each get/set call.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like the decision behind panicking is to avoid the control flow branch, which seems like a subjective design decision. But I appreciate the answer.

RE the important detail being **request-scoped**: I agree and that is why the `WithContext` would be utilized on a per request basis that is then passed in at each get/set call. I'll update the example to show this.

Answer (score 0):

The context of an HTTP request is canceled if the client closes the connection. When the context is canceled, all its child contexts are also canceled, so a nil context would panic then. Because of this, you cannot pass a nil context to `WithContext`.

Whether or not your redis store should panic depends on how you are going to use that context. It is usually not a good idea to include a context in a struct. One acceptable way of doing that is if the struct itself is a context. Contexts should be created for each call, should live for the duration of that call, and then thrown away.

Comment: Regarding your first point, that makes sense and thank you for pointing that out. But the part that is not clear to me is, why panic? Couldn't they return `(*Request, error)` and what implications does that have for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Regarding your second point, that also makes sense and I completely agree but am not too sure what else to do. The idea in this case would be that the store could be re-created with context on a per-request basis in some middleware and thrown away at the end of the middleware chain.

Comment: Does the store need the context? You can create a store and put that into a context.